# How to find the count of values in nested queries

Tags: sql, mysql, hive

I am trying to find the count of records from one nested SQL but facing error.
Cannot recognise input near in subquery sequence

Please find the query below

```
Select count(*) from
(Select emp as `bd`,wrk as `Zn`,dept as `dd` from 
(
Select emp,wrk,dept,far,atn,dec,Jan,set
From table name where dept = "IT")static_inner_qry_alias
Group by emp,wrk,dept limit 1200)
```

Comment: I don't recognise the error 'Cannot recognise input near in subquery sequence`.  However, I note that your derived table is missing an alias, maybe that's related?

Comment: Yes.added alias and it doesn't come.Thanks

Comment: I see only one alias in your question, but you have two derived tables.  Please could you update the question to show the code that you have tried, and confirm the exact error message that you're seeing?

Comment: Also `From table name` is not valid syntax - what is the actual name of the table?

Answer (score 0):

I see the code snippet got issues with the aliasing of the columns using backticks. **In SQL, you should use double quotes or square brackets to alias columns, not backticks.**

Modified code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
    SELECT emp AS "bd", wrk AS "Zn", dept AS "dd"
    FROM
    (
        SELECT emp, wrk, dept, far, atn, dec, Jan, set
        FROM table_name
        WHERE dept = 'IT'
    ) static_inner_qry_alias
    GROUP BY emp, wrk, dept
    LIMIT 1200
) AS subquery_alias;
```

I did add an alias for the outer subquery. This should work without errors.

If still there is an issue with the query, then most probably, due to the use of the `LIMIT` clause within the subquery. Give it a try!